# Choosing programming language: Text-based adventure game

Tags: programming-languages, game-engine, development-environment, adventure

Since I'm finally on summer holidays, I have been wanting to sit down and develop an idea for a text-based adventure game I have.

As such, I'm curious to know **which language you would recommend** for writing said game. Or rather; what was/is the industry standard?

I'm not to keen on using Quest (or similar tools), but that may change if highly recommended.

Nonetheless: **Which language should I opt for when developing a text-based adventure**?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use a specialized tool such as [Inform](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inform7) or TADS. You can start [there](http://brasslantern.org). The major *pro* of such solutions is that they are specialized -- as opposed to a general-purpose programming language for which you will inevitably end up writing domain-specific stuff, and usually of poor quality.

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest 2 options: **C++** & **Javascript**.

**WHY *C++?***

1. Chose C++ if you are making this game to learn something. And learning C++ is best to start with.
2. Although, the game you are talking about doesn't seem too complex, but still you can play with powerful features off C++.
3. And it is fast.(Although that will hardaly make any difference in this case).

***So, from learning point of view, C++ seems best choice.***

**WHY *JAVASCRIPT?***

1. It's simple, fast, easy and fun. Even if you dont know anything about javascript you can start coding in it in a couple of days.
2. Another benefit will be that if you make your game in javascript,it will be platform independent i.e you can simply run it in any browser on any machine. Isn't it awesome?
3. **BUT** to use javascript you have to create a HTML page() which is pretty simple too). But if you can do it, you can also give a nice game-like graphic interface to your text input.

> So, Happy Coding & Gaming !!

Comment: actually no html page is needed, node.js has readline.

Answer (score 1):

Symbolic programming languages in general, and logic programming languages in particular, can be a good choice as they make it very easy to express the rules that define the options at each state of the game and their consequences for each option. For some examples see:

https://github.com/LogtalkDotOrg/logtalk3/tree/master/examples/adventure

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need much more than text i/o and basic datastructures (lists, maybe dictionaries, and strings/symbols) so **the best choice is the one you enjoy the most**, because losing fun is the most often gamedev killer.

If you plan to have fancy input structure you might enjoy python with it's nltk (on the other hand you usually don't need much nlp to recognize a dozen of verbs and a few dozen of nouns).

If you're thinking about rich world interactions, you'll probably do better with some modern dynamically typed, garbage collected language (scheme [despite long history it's *very* modern], commonlisp, elixir, ruby, python, and js come to mind), or -- if you're not afraid of experimenting -- prolog.

As of industry, I don't know what's going on now, but Zork series was developed in ZIL (Zork Implementation Language), a [strange] lisp variant, and some 2000s games were developed in [variants of] Inform (which is ridiculously close to English).